# how to remove a blank line after removing an unwanted line in perl?

Tags: perl

For example, I want to remove unwanted line with bbbb

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

I use the following perl regular expression to accomplish this.

```
$_ =~ s/bbbb//g;
```

The problem here is that a blank line is stays, for example

```
aaaa

cccc
dddd
```

I need to remove the unwanted text line and also the blank line.

Comment: Do you have the whole data in `$_` or are you somehow loop & printing?

Comment: line by line, I don't have the whole data in $_, just line by line

Comment: then why not just stop printing empty lines? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply include the newline in your regular expression:

```
$_ =~ s/bbbb\n//g;
```

This will result in:

```
aaaa
cccc
dddd
```

Comment: In fact, it worked out just fine.  I tested before posting; please do the same.  `perl -p -e 's/bbbb\n//g' < input` yields exactly the output above given exactly the input above.

Comment: @larsks, indeed it does work. i edited my answer to remove the nonsense. and removed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you are reading this line by line you could just have your loop do this:

```
my @foo = (
    "aaaa\n",
    "bbbb\n",
    "cccc\n",
    "dddd\n" );

foreach my $line ( @foo ) {
    next if ( $line =~ /^bbbb$/ );

    # now do something with a valid line;
}
```